# How do subscriptions in pycups or cups work?

Tags: python, printing, printers, cups

I'm writing a python script that let's me lookup print jobs. So far my research has led me to this:

1. Import the pycups module (named `cups`)
2. You need to create a subscription, that logs printer events
3. From the subscription you get details of each print job

The pycups API documentation has the following method:

```
# connection.createSubscription(...)

# createSubscription(uri, events=[], job_id=-1, recipient_uri=,
#     lease_duration=-1, time_interval=-1, user_data=) -> integer
```

Could someone please explain the parameters used here and their meaning, especially `uri`, `recipient_uri` and `events` ?

Answer (score 2):

This module <s>has</s> had a good [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/pycups/cups.Connection-class.html#createSubscription).

The parameters, you are asking about are as follows:

- `uri`: The uri of the CUPS-server (e.g. ipp://localhost:631/)
- [`recipient_uri`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3995#section-5.3.1): A listener uri to receive subscribed notifications
  on (e.g. http://localhost: <PORT_OF_YOUR_APPLICATION>)
- [`events`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3995#section-5.3.3): list of events you want to subscribe to (e.g. `job-completed`)

Given you process is listening on port `9988` you could subscribe to completed jobs like this:

```
subscription_id = cups_connection.createSubscription(
    uri='ipp://localhost:631',
    recipient_uri='http://localhost:9988',
    events=['job-completed']
)
```

Comment: The link to the documentation is broken